# ACSL Logic Struct Declarations Not Working as in Reference Manual

Tags: frama-c, acsl

I would like to have a way to describe logic/spec level structs that include abstract lists. Example 2.2.7 on page 27 of the [ACSL Reference Manual](https://frama-c.com/download/acsl.pdf) suggests that there is a 
 way to do this and it is as follows:

```
//@ type point = struct { real x; real y; };
//@ type triangle = point[3];
//@ logic point origin = { .x = 0.0 , .y = 0.0 };
/*@ logic triangle t_iso = { [0] = origin,
@ [1] = { .y = 2.0 , .x = 0.0 }
@ [2] = { .x = 2.0 , .y = 0.0 }};
@*/
/*@ logic point centroid(triangle t) = {
@ .x = mean3(t[0].x,t[1].x,t[2].x);
@ .y = mean3(t[0].y,t[1].y,t[2].y);
@ };
@*/
//@ type polygon = point[];
/*@ logic perimeter(polygon p) =
@ \sum(0,\length(p)-1,\lambda integer i;d(p[i],p[(i+1) % \length(p)])) ;
@*/
```

If I copy/paste this exact code into a text editor and try to run this code with the wp plugin with:

`frama-c -wp -wp-rte -wp-prover alt-ergo shapes.c`

I get an error:

`[kernel:annot-error] shapes.c:1: Warning: unexpected token '{'`

If I give up on trying to write logic/spec level declarations of struct types, but would still like to write logic/spec level expressions that instantiate structs defined in C as follows:

```
struct somestruct {
     int x;
     int y;
 };

/*@
     logic struct somestruct foo = { .x = 3, .y = 4 };
*/
```

I still get an error:

```
[kernel:annot-error] aggregate_err.c:7: Warning:
  unsupported aggregated field construct. Ignoring global annotation
```

and not having a way to write particular values of structs as expressions in specifications leads to some fairly ugly specifications, so I am hoping that I am doing something wrong.

If I dig into the source of frama-C 20.0 to try to find the part of the parser-generator code for `/*@ type` declarations, it looks like the syntax in Ex 2.2.7 is not really implemented. It looks like the syntax for type level declarations is line 799 of 
frama-c-20.0-Calcium/src/kernel_internals/parsing/logic_parser.mly
(called type_spec)
And the parse rule for type level declarations of structs is:

```
| STRUCT exit_rt_type identifier_or_typename { LTstruct $3 }
```

which looks like it would support

`//@ type foo = struct c_struct;`

but not something like what Ex 2.2.7 has as in:

`//@ type point = struct { real x; real y; };`

Is there something else I should be doing to have better support for structs in ACSL/Frama-C? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all ACSL constructions are supported by the current Frama-C implementation. With each Frama-C release comes an ACSL implementation manual, which describes the constructions that are not yet implemented. For Frama-C 20.0 Calcium, this can be found [here](https://frama-c.com/download/acsl-implementation-20.0-Calcium.pdf). In this document, unsupported constructions appear in red **in the relevant BNF rule**. Note however that other parts of the manual are left untouched. Notably, the fact that an example is included in the implementation manual *does not imply* that it is expected to be successfully parsed by the current Frama-C version. In your case, these are the rules of figure 2.17 on page 57, which show that indeed records are not implemented.

As you have already discovered by yourselves, it is indeed possible to define a C `struct` (possibly `ghost`) and an ACSL type out of it. Of course, since the `struct` lives in the C world, its fields must have C types (ACSL types in ghost declarations is unsupported as well).

Similarly, you can simulate the absence of direct record definition by an update (the `\with` construction) of all the fields of an arbitrary record, as in the following example:

```c
//@ ghost struct c_s { float x; float y; };

//@ type point = struct c_s;

//@ axiomatic Arbitrary_point { logic point empty; }

//@ logic point my_point = {{ empty \with .x = (float)1. } \with .y = (float)2.};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The example that causes a syntax error is actually still in the implementation manual that you linked as well (it is Example 2.12 in Section 2.2.7 on page 27). If I copy and paste this example verbatim, I still get this same error. The text does not make it seem like it is intended that this Example should not work. frama-c -version yields 20.0 (Calcium), and the command I am running is frama-c -wp -wp-prover alt-ergo ex2.12.c. Can you (or someone) repeat my error? Or is my environment doing something unexpected?

Comment: I am also getting other syntax errors that surprise me. For example:

 99 /*@
100     logic struct mpool abs_mpool_free(struct mpool *p, struct mpool_entry *ptr) =
101         { *p \with
102             .entry_list = { p->entry_list \with {.next = *p } }
103         };
104 */

gives me an error:
[kernel:annot-error] mpool.spec:102: Warning: unexpected token '{'

even though this looks valid according to the reference manual. Dropping the braces around the expression on the RHS of entry_list does not look valid to me and does also give an error about an unexpected.

Comment: @AndrewFerraiuolo regarding your first comment, this is what I tried to convey in my answer by saying that only BNF descriptions contain implementation details. Examples are left untouched in the implementation manual, but there's no commitment that they will be parsed by Frama-C if the relevant BNF entries indicate unsupported features. I've edited my answer to put more emphasis on this fact. Regarding your second comment, I think that it deserves a question of its own, as the format of SO comments makes it quite difficult to speak about any non-trivial piece of code.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for mis-reading. I read it thoroughly shortly after you replied initially, then forgot this bit of detail when I went back to look at the implementation manual again much later.